# SSH is not working on RPI?

Tags: ssh, pi-3b+, raspberry-pi-os, openssh

My Rpi was working fine before. after I power it up again it and accessing via **ssh pi@192.168.154.38** and its returning "permission denied, try again". then I have done some changes in root/etc/ssh/sshd_config as suggested by many people on google. but nothing worked. so i erase my sd card and flash the Rasbian in it. after that is happening. **ssh pi@192.168.154.38** just keep waiting and nothing returned.

[image]

Comment: DO NOT post pictures of text post TEXT!

Comment: how long after you run the ssh command do you hit ctrl-z - putting the ssh command "to sleep" in the background?? Why are you showing installing openssh-**server** on your client machine?

Comment: @Bravo because most of the people have asked this question before, in their comment section people who answered them asked them to run install open-ssh, start ssh services and enable it... so I have done these steps to show that I have tried these solution already.

Comment: yes, but that should be run on the `pi` ... why are you running it on your lenovo running ubunti?